# Cannot load model after running blender and installing add-on

Tags: modeling, add-on, import, error, encoding

I used blender 2.79 2.80 2.90 and when I clicked the import model bottom after installing the Cats plug-in each add-on, I got an import error except for 2.79, and I need a quick and realistic solution to this.[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a file with characters that aren't recognized by the add-on parser (Unicode).

Comment: This looks like the add-on fails to set the encoding to UTF-8 thus using your system locale to determine the encoding.